# Inconsistent HTMLMediaElement duration

Tags: javascript, video, html5-video, dom-events, hls.js

I'm having an issue with my video player where the video duration returned from [HTMLMediaElement.duration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/duration) is not consistent. I set up the following listener to help illustrate:

```
video.addEventListener('timeupdate', function(e) {
    console.log('Duration: ' + video.duration);
    if ( video.currentTime === video.duration ) {
        console.log( video.currentTime + ' === ' + video.duration )
    }
});
```

When I seek all the way to the end of the video, this event returns a different (more exact) value. I'll provide an example of my logs below:

```
Duration: NaN
Duration: 135.8357
Duration: 135.8357
Duration: 135.8357
Duration: 135.8357
Duration: 135.8357
Duration: 135.8357
...
```

*..I seek to the end of the video..*

```
...
Duration: 135.8357
135.8357 === 135.8357
Duration: 135.952833
```

I seek all the way to the end of the video, the current time is equal to the duration, and then the duration updates to a different time. Seeking all the way to the end of the video does not fire the `ended` event (unless the video resumes and hits the new end point of `135.952833`).

Does anyone have any insight into this issue or thoughts on a possible solution?

Comment: Do i guess right that this changes depending on container/codec you use, also it is different in chrome and firefox? Do you know if audio and video is exactly the same lenght in the clip?

Comment: Good point by @Harry on audio track. Indeed if you read the specification text [duration-change-algorithm](http://w3c.github.io/media-source/#duration-change-algorithm) you will see that this is related to multiple sourceBuffers.

Comment: Nice finding, but it only means that the element is allowed to change duration whenever it finds the need to do so. I guess audio and video is not the same duration in your clip but i don't think they show 120ms difference (diff should be typically less than one video frame duration). Can you maybe share a very short example clip and update your question with your results for this very clip? [EDIT] actually 135sec is short enough, maybe you can share the very clip you got those results from...

Comment: @KGraber Can you share the video? Without the container/codec it is hard to tell, but I've actually also encountered and reported an error to Chromium, where in case of mp4 the timestamps are not calculated properly due to an old ffmpeg branch being used.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue but with an audio element. When seeking to the end point of the audio, `durationchange` event was constantly triggered, `audio.duration` keeps changing for several seconds.

Turned out to be the audio source's problem. Here's a fiddle of the problematic audio: https://jsfiddle.net/jessuni/kxcmye8z/42/
Have you tried another video source and reproduce the issue?