# HTMLMediaElement.duration for .ogg files is inconsistent

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

I'm trying to do precise timing on audio files using HTMLMediaElement.duration. But on Chrome, when playing an .ogg file, in the last couple seconds of audio, the duration value changes. Here's a simplified example that demonstrated the problem. I generated a 5s .ogg file of pink noise using Audacity and used it as a source.

```
<audio id="audio" controls>
    <source src="./noise.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
</audio>
```

Then logged the duration on every timeupdate event.

```
audio.addEventListener('timeupdate', function() {
    console.log(audio.duration);
})
```

At first, it outputs "5" 10 times, but then changes to "5.000997" for another 11 times. Another file outputted "31.318662" and "31.320816". What's causing this?

Related: [Inconsistent HTMLMediaElement duration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53104649/inconsistent-htmlmediaelement-duration)

Comment: Have you tried waiting for the `loadedmetadata` event and then logging the duration? Its also possible that this kind of file changes duration as more data is loaded, at least that would be my first hunch.

Comment: @somethinghere As the file is local, it loads almost instantly, way before I manually start the playback. I could sit there not pressing play for ages, and it will correctly return "5" as the duration right after I do. Only when I reach the last few seconds of the audio, the duration changes permanently.

Comment: That seems to indicate that OGG files are loaded on an as-needed basis, to be honest. Maybe check out when the `canplaythrough` event is fired? Set the `preload` attribute?

Comment: @somethinghere `canplaythrough` is fired right after `loadedmetadata` by default, but if I change `preload` to `auto`, they're loaded when I press play. I found something peculiar though. When I seek the audio past the end, it increases the duration (for .ogg files in Chrome).